# freetds start job at step from linux python script on MSSQL DB

Tags: linux, sql-server, python, freetds

I'm trying to create a python script on a linux box that can execute an agent job.

Looking around I found `sp_start_job` command. But it doesn't seem to exist on python.

Does any one know if it does work on python or any other scripting language executable on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work.

It would python but in the end decided to do it with bash with FreeTDS like this:

```
~$TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H serverIPaddress -p portnumber -U domain\\username EOS
>EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'jobname' ;
>GO
>EOS
```

it will prompt for password...

this can go in to a script to execute (whenever) probably call it from a python script or just schedule with cron.